# How to copy files found with grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, cp

I am running this command to find all my files that contain (with help of regex)"someStrings" in a tree directory.

```
grep -lir '^beginString' ./ -exec cp -r {} /home/user/DestinationFolder \;
```

It found files like this:

```
FOLDER
a.txt
-->SUBFOLDER
  a.txt
---->SUBFOLDER
     a.txt
```

I want to copy all files and folder, with the same schema, to the destination folder, but i don't know how to do it. It's important copy files and folder, because several files found has the same name and I need to keep it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '^beginString' {} \; -exec cp -t /home/user/DestinationFolder {} +
```

or

```
grep -lir '^beginString' . | xargs cp -t /home/user/DestinationFolder
```

But if you want to keep directory structure, you could:

```
grep -lir '^beginString' . | tar -T - -c | tar -xpC /home/user/DestinationFolder
```

or if like myself, you prefer to be sure about kind of file you store (only file, no symlinks), you could:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l '^beginString' {} + | tar -T - -c |
    tar -xpC /home/user/DestinationFolder
```

and if your files names could countain **spaces and/or special characters**, use *`null terminated strings`* for passing `grep -l` output (arg `-Z`) to `tar -T` (arg `--null -T`):

```
grep -Zlir '^beginString' . | xargs --null cp -t /home/user/DestinationFolder
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lZ '^beginString' {} + | tar --null  -T - -c |
    tar -xpC /home/user/DestinationFolder
```

Comment: awesome, it works!!! I don't kwon how do it but works!
The command make some backup files, I deleted it manually and fine. Thanks my friend!!! You saved my life

Comment: Nice encyclopedia of rare parameters, thanks for sharing :-)