# How to copy files found with grep on OSX

Tags: macos, grep, pipe, xargs, cp

I'm wanting to copy files I've found with `grep` on an OSX system, where the `cp` command doesn't have a `-t` option.

[A previous posts' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396487/how-to-copy-files-found-with-grep) for doing something like this relied on the `-t` flag in `cp`. However, like that poster, I want to take the file list I receive from `grep` and then execute a command over it, something like:

`grep -lr "foo" --include=*.txt * 2>/dev/null | xargs cp -t /path/to/targetdir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less efficient than `cp -t`, but this works:

```
grep -lr "foo" --include=*.txt * 2>/dev/null |
  xargs -I{} cp "{}" /path/to/targetdir
```

Explanation:

For `filenames | xargs cp -t destination`, `xargs` changes the incoming filenames into this format:

```
cp -t destination filename1 ... filenameN
```

i.e., it only runs `cp` once (actually, once for every few thousand filenames -- `xargs` breaks the command line up if it would be too long for the shell).

For `filenames | xargs -I{} cp "{}" destination`, on the other hand, `xargs` changes the incoming filenames into this format:

```
cp "filename1" destination
...
cp "filenameN" destination
```

i.e., it runs `cp` once for each incoming filename, which is much slower. For a large number (e.g., >10k) of very small (e.g., <10k) files, I'd guess it could even be thousands of times slower. But it does work :)

PS: Another popular technique is use `find`'s `exec` function instead of `xargs`, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241677/1563960

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is, if you have admin privileges or can persuade your sysadmin, to install the `coreutils` package as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973942/4355474), and follow the steps but for `cp` rather than `ls`.