# How to install and use GNU "ls" on macOS?

Tags: macos, directory, homebrew, gnu, ls

I was following [this](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) article to update my bash. I really want to update my version of bash so that I can use the `--group-directories-first` option for the `ls` command.

So far I have accomplished the following from the linked article:

- I successfully executed the `brew install bash` command and downloaded the new bash. Per the article I can verify that the the `/usr/local/bin/bash --version` on my machine shows the following:

  > GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0)
  >   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU
  >   GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
  >
  > This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
  >   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

  - I completed the `sudo vim /etc/shells` command, editing the file to include the new downloaded bash. This is what it looks like:

[image]

- I executed the `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash` to set the new bash as default.

However, even after I close the terminal and relaunch it, I am not sure if I am using the new terminal. This is because:

1. when I execute `bash --version` I get the following:

   > GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0)
   >   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   >   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
   >
   > This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
   >   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

But when I run `echo $BASH_VERSION` I get something to the contrary (`3.2.57(1)-release`). Isn't that the old verison?

2. Also, the new "group directories first" command still doesn't work. I get the following error when I run `ls --group-directories-first`:

> ls: illegal option -- - usage: ls
>   [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: could you tell the output of `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @Mihir I got as the output `/bin/bash`. Does this mean I missed a step in my configuration?

Comment: Not really. I did the same steps (except I use macports as the package manager) and it works fine for me.

Comment: `ls` is not part of `bash`. `ls` is in [Coreutils - GNU core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

Comment: @pynexj then perhaps this may be a misunderstanding on my part. Would it be possible to update my machine so that I am using the new features of `ls`? Not sure what exactly I would update in this case.

Comment: ah completely forgot that, `ls` is a separate utility, not a part of `bash`.

Comment: @Mihir I found this article (https://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/). It more or less describes what I see (difference between `--version` and `$BASH_VERSION`) but I am not sure how their solution addresses my issue. Should that discrepancy be of any concern at this point?

Comment: try `brew install coreutils`. commands installed with `brew` may have added the prefix `g`. e.g. `ls` vs. `gls`, `find` vs. `gfind`.

Comment: @pynexj I have just now brewed installed `coreutils`. My `ls --group-directories-first` still doesn't work. Is there an extra step needed after I install it? I have already tried shutting down / quitting the terminal and relaunching it.

Comment: Isn't this more a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @pynexj Thank you ! Looks like it works now. My issue has been solved. You are correct that there is a prefix g for the command. I've lost my custom color output though (I had my alias ls refer to `ls -Gla` where my colors were configured through LSCOLORS). Thanks again for the help—I appreciate it.

Comment: @im2wddrf, not expd with `brew`, making a guess you can find the location of coreutils by `brew info coreutils` and then find `ls` there, idk if `brew` already adds it to path. but in any case, you can add it to path by urself.

Comment: @im2wddrf gnu ls has --color=auto

Comment: @pynexj right. I have the following in my bash profile `alias ls='gls -Gla --color=auto --group-directories-first'`. When I tinker with my LSCOLORS it doesn't really change the color of the directory, just defaults to blue.

Comment: @im2wddrf `gls` doesn't use `LSCOLORS`; it uses `LS_COLORS`. Please read the documentation for `gls`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `bash`. Command `ls` is not a builtin of `bash`.

macOS is based on the Unix operating system. Some of its basic commands are BSD flavored. The `--group-directories-first` option you want is available in GNU `ls` only. All you need is a GNU flavored `ls`.

Solution: install `coreutils`, in which GNU `ls` is included.

```sh
brew install coreutils
```

Add the following code into `~/.bash_profile`, to prioritize the `ls` command and other GNU flavored commands over the builtin BSD flavored command in macOS.

```sh
# Make all GNU flavor commands available, may override same-name BSD flavor commands
# For x86 Mac
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:${PATH}"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:${MANPATH}"

# For M1 Mac
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:${PATH}"
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:${MANPATH}"
```

If you only want the GNU `ls` but not other GNU flavored commands. Don't add the above content, but create an alias in `~/.bash_profile`.

```sh
# For x86 Mac
alias ls="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls"

# For M1 Mac
alias ls="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls"
```

Here's all commands brought by `coreutils`.

```sh
❯ ls /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
'['         cat      cksum    dd          echo     fmt      install   ls       mv       od         printf     rmdir       sha384sum   split    tac       tr         unexpand   wc
 b2sum      chcon    comm     df          env      fold     join      md5sum   nice     paste      ptx        runcon      sha512sum   stat     tail      true       uniq       who
 base32     chgrp    cp       dir         expand   groups   kill      mkdir    nl       pathchk    pwd        seq         shred       stdbuf   tee       truncate   unlink     whoami
 base64     chmod    csplit   dircolors   expr     head     link      mkfifo   nohup    pinky      readlink   sha1sum     shuf        stty     test      tsort      uptime     yes
 basename   chown    cut      dirname     factor   hostid   ln        mknod    nproc    pr         realpath   sha224sum   sleep       sum      timeout   tty        users
 basenc     chroot   date     du          false    id       logname   mktemp   numfmt   printenv   rm         sha256sum   sort        sync     touch     uname      vdir
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely consider adding that to my bash profile to see if the newer commands are of use. Thanks!